Blazor 8.0 - issues using DataAnnotationValidator and ValidationSummary
I am currently following a tutorial to learn Blazor (I'm working in 8.0).
I have a MessageWall.razor file, containing:
    @page "/MessageWall"

    <h3>MessageWall</h3>

    <EditForm Model="model" OnValidSubmit="ValidSubmission" FormName="MessageWallForm">
        <DataAnnotationsValidator />
        <ValidationSummary />

        <label for="message" class="form-label">@nameof(model.Message)</label>
        <InputText id="message" @bind-Value="model.Message" class="form-control" />

        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </EditForm>

    <ul>
        @foreach (string message in messages)
        {
            <li>@message</li>
        }
    </ul>

    @code {
        private MessageModel model = new();
        private List<string> messages = new();
        private void ValidSubmission()
        {
            messages.Add(model.Message);
            model = new();
        }
    }

and a MessageModel.cs (contained within a Models folder, which I added to @_Imports.razor using @using BlazorServerMessageWall.Models):

namespace BlazorServerMessageWall.Models;

public class MessageModel
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(10, MinimumLength = 5)]
    public string Message { get; set; }

}

When I fire up the application, and enter a valid entry (eg; "hello", "123456") I get "The Message field is required."
Really baffled here, read through the documentation. What am I doing incorrectly? Nothing in the console to indicate there are any problems.

Which image? What is the error or inconsistency that you get?

When do you get the message? On form submit or during typing?

@RahulSharma On submit - nothing happens during typing

Here's a slightly refactored version of your page that works:
@page "/"
@page "/"
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

<h3>MessageWall</h3>

<EditForm Model="model" OnValidSubmit="ValidSubmission" FormName="MessageWallForm">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />

    <label for="message" class="form-label">@nameof(model.Message)</label>
    <InputText id="message" @bind-Value="model.Message" class="form-control" />

    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
</EditForm>

<ul>
    @foreach (string message in messages)
    {
        <li>@message</li>
    }
</ul>

@code {
    private MessageModel model = new();
    private List<string> messages = new();
    private void ValidSubmission()
    {
        messages.Add(model.Message);
        model = new();
    }
    public class MessageModel
    {
        [Required]
        [StringLength(10, MinimumLength = 5)]
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
}

So there's something else you are showing us.

Unfortunately this did not work, it resulted in: "InvalidOperationException: EditForm requires either a Model parameter, or an EditContext parameter, please provide one of these." when I attempted this solution (this was after copying your code directly).
As for the "something else" I'm afraid I'm not sure what it could be. This is otherwise a completely new Blazor project, the only other changes are:
Creation of a "Models" folder inside the solution, adding the MessageModel.cs (shown above) to that folder, adding the line mentioned above to _Imports, and creating the MessageWall.razor page

Deploy a new Net8, Server, Global project and copy the code above to Home and it will work.

The solution was to add @rendermode InteractiveServer to the top of my .razor page!

"So there's something else you are showing us." - Your render mode!
